# Switch to a new model of permissions

Tags: android, permissions, publish

I have an app in Google Play. Now I want to upload a new version. But when I upload an apk, get this message:

Switch to a new model of permissions

> ATTENTION! Users of APK-file version 4992 for SDK 22 and below can
>   install this APK- file. However, after the upgrade, they will not be
>   able to install the APK  files for the SDK 22 or lower. TIP If this
>   change was made specifically, make sure that all future versions of 
>   the application that contain this APK file are designed for SDK 23 and
>   higher.

4992 - is the latest version of my app before update.
My minSdkVersion is 15. 
 
Here are the permissions my app uses:
    CAMERA, 
    ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION 
    USE_FINGERPRINT 
    INTERNET

As I realize, now I can update my app using minSdkVersion 15. 
 
Now I want to know, whether I will be able to update my app again after this one using minSdkVersion 15. If not, why has this problem appeared and are there other ways to solve this? 
 
Thanks fow answers

Answer (score 1):

As android introduce new permission model for v23 & above. You can follow from here https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

You can keep v15 minimum there should be not issue!

I hope this will help!

Comment: if you satisfied with answer please check right sign. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because of targetSDK version changed to 23 or higher.
It seems for version 4992, your targetSDK version was 22 or below.
With API 23, run-time permission are enabled